# Vue + chartjs : Nearest point on hover tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, chart.js, tooltip

I'm currently trying to get my tooltip's chart (vuejs + chartjs) running as following :

[image: Chart js · Interactions with nearest mode]
([Source](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/tooltip/interactions.html) with "mode: nearest, axis: xy" mode selected)

Here is my code for the component :

```
Vue.component('line-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Line,
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['Dec 2017', 'Jan 2018', 'Feb 2018', 'Mar 2018', 'Apr 2018', 'May 2018', 'Jun 2018', 'Jul 2018', 'Aug 2018', 'Sep 2018', 'Oct 2018', 'Nov 2018'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: '2018 pages read per month',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: [1238, 1660, 1571, 976, 2344, 1227, 949, 1109, 900, 458, 240, 384]
        }
      ]
    }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false, 

        //Here is the part that doesn't seem to work
        interaction: {
         axis: 'xy', 
         mode: 'nearest',
         intersect: false

        }
       })
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { }
});
```

You can find my [codepen here](https://codepen.io/saveup/pen/vYWxdyJ)

According to the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/tooltip/interactions.html) I can't figure out what i'm missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After paraphrasing my question to the extreme, I just found a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/ZeaLGj) whose code doesn't match the documentation BUT it answers my question perfectly.

So to get the result, you have to use `options.tooltips.mode` and not `options.interaction.mode` !

Then, you have to change :

```
    interaction: {
     axis: 'xy', 
     mode: 'nearest',
     intersect: false

    }
```

By :

```
tooltips: {
  mode: 'index',
  intersect: false,
},
```

Here is the final code :

```
Vue.component('line-chart', {
      extends: VueChartJs.Line,
      mounted () {
        this.renderChart({
          labels: ['Dec 2017', 'Jan 2018', 'Feb 2018', 'Mar 2018', 'Apr 2018', 'May 2018', 'Jun 2018', 'Jul 2018', 'Aug 2018', 'Sep 2018', 'Oct 2018', 'Nov 2018'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: '2018 pages read per month',
              backgroundColor: '#f87979',
              data: [1238, 1660, 1571, 976, 2344, 1227, 949, 1109, 900, 458, 240, 384]
            }
          ]
        }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false, 
              tooltips: {
             axis: 'xy', 
             mode: 'nearest',
             intersect: false
    
            }
           })
      }
    });
    
    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: { }
    });
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/saveup/pen/ZEaexLL) working as excepted with tooltips in nearest mode on hovering the chart's line.

Final Result :
[image]